# Android Proguard please correct the above warnings

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm actually developing an application, I have the following Proguard error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

It refers to:

```
Warning:there were 162 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

So I can't generate my APK. It seems that the problem happened when I used *multiDexEnabled* in the config. Before that (as I remember) I didn't get this error at all.

Here is my Gradle settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id2tel.nextgen"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 10
        versionName "0.0.10"
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+"
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.8.0'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.0.+'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'

}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is my Proguard config file:

```
-keep class com.fasterxml.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.*

-keep class com.squareup.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.*

-keep class org.springframework.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.springframework.*

-keep class org.json.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.json.*
```

Note: Having this code in my proguard-rules or proguard-android doesn't change anything at all concerning the error stack.

Can you help me resolve this problem?

EDIT : fullstack error:

> Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
>   :app:collectReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Root
>   :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
>   :app:prepareJpCoCyberagentAndroidGpuimageGpuimageLibrary123Library
>   UP-TO-DATE Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl Information:95 warnings
>   :app:prepareComAstuetzPagerslidingtabstrip101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
>            In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareJpWasabeefPicassoTransformations104Library UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedOutput
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex100Library UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
>   Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning:Dependency
>   org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting
>   with the internal version provided by Android. Information:1 error
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput
>   :app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>            In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   Information:Total time: 6.528 secs
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
>   :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody :app:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
>   :app:proguardRelease FAILED
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Response :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:checkReleaseManifest
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.client.OkHttpRequestFactory: can't
>   find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
>   :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.client.OkHttpRequestFactory: can't
>   find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
>   Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
>   can't find referenced class
>   com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
>            the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps730Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
> >     :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132103Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find
> >     referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
> >              In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader:
> >     can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory
> >     :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig$Feature
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
> >     :app:preBuild Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't
> >     find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
> >     :app:preDebugBuild :app:lintVitalRelease
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody Warning:there were 162
> >     unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find
> >     referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.client.OkHttpRequestFactory: can't
> >     find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
> >     :app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby730Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.RssChannelHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.rss.Channel
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
> >     :app:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton180Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedOutput
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
> >     :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet730Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
> >     :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
> >              If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices730Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.atom.Feed
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus730Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:preReleaseBuild :app:proguardRelease
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
> >     :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama730Library
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE Information:See
> >     complete output in console
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
> >     Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
> >     class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
> >              In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class
> >     org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig$Feature
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.client.OkHttpRequestFactory: can't
> >     find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
> >     Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:
> >     can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory

Comment: can you post 162 line code

Comment: I edit to show the fullstack error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986264/android-proguard-with-httpcore-and-httpmime-using-android-studio-and-gradle

Answer (score 4):

Most of all libraries need to have own proguard dependency in your proguard file. Please, check the documentation for each library. 
And try to see this https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries . I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adding
 -ignorewarnings

in proguard-rules.pro file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding below lines

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```